# MySQL search text in best performance

Tags: mysql, search, indexing

Is there any way to search on specific text in MySQL without using the Full Text Search
I know LIKE is a solution but using wildcard at the beginning will disable using indexes , therefore not best performance for large data

Comment: Please add some sample data which explains your question.

Comment: There are 3 options: string searching functions (while searching in the middle index not used), regular expression search (index not used), full-text search. Select one...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i need a method to do similar of what LIKE does but with index included for performance 
i.e : Select * from Files where Name LIKE '%est%';
so it returns any Name contains these letters "est"

Answer (score 0):

Please specify more details of *your* use case.

Meanwhile, I have found this to be beneficial in some use cases.  For example, suppose you wanted to search for a bracketed word:

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND col LIKE '%[word]%'
```

The `MATCH` would rapidly find the few rows with "word", then the `LIKE` would slowly check those few rows.  It gives reasonably fast overall speed while checking for some types of non-words.